# how to have different labels for formset data entry fields in django template

Tags: django, templates, label, formset

i have made the following template and view for my form,what i want is to have different labels name specifically the ids stored in the array for each data entry field.Plz guide me how to achieve  this

```
def show (request):

b = request.session["s1"] # count of no of period ids
c = request.session["s2"] # account number inserted by user
d = request.session["s3"] # year inserted by customer
a = account_period.objects.filter(year=d).values('id')
e = account_period.objects.filter(year=d).values('month')
f = account_period.objects.filter(id = a).values('year')
butt = formset_factory(bu, extra=b)
if request.method == 'POST'
 formset = butt(request.POST)
 if formset.is_valid():

    z = account_tab.objects.get(account_number=c)
    pr = date.today()
    i=0
    for form in formset.forms:
       x = form.cleaned_data['value']
       y = account_period.objects.get(id=a[i:(i+1)])
       try:
        uip = budget.objects.get(account_no = c,account_period = a[i:(i+1)])
        if uip.budget_amount != x
          uip.budget_amount = x
          uip.save()

       except budget.DoesNotExist:
        w = budget(account_no = z, account_period = y, budget_amount = x, created_by_login = 'me')
        w.save()
       i=i+1
    pass
  return HttpResponse('thanks')


else:
  formset = butt(
   return render_to_response('budgetfinalform.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,'formset': formset},context_instance=RequestContext(request))



<html>
<head>
<title>BUDGET</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>BUDGET MANAGEMENTS</p>
<p>Your Account Number is : {{ account_number }}.</p> <p>You Chose {{ period }} {{month}} as period<p>   
{% if form.errors %}
<p style="color: red;">
    Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
</p>
{% endif %} 
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
<table>
{% for form in formset.forms %}
{{ form }}
{% endfor %}
</table>    
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best way to this is to customize the form and edit the field labels in your view before sending it to the template.

Comment: My field labels are dynamic and are stored in the array 'a'.Also number of entries in array = no of data entry fields in the form.I have added the code of my view and i want to have the values of array 'a' to be the label of the formset data entry fields. e.g.,if user selects year 2000 in my GUI, the field labels will be Jan 2000, Feb 2000,...,Nov 2000, Dec 2000 etc. It will follow similar pattern for the year chosen.